# Running a cron job every five minutes

Tags: cronjob

I need to run a cron for sync command. Is it as simple as this?

```
*/5 * * * * --sync
```

Which I think will run the sync command every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I believe yes.

**Linux Crontab Format**:

```
MIN HOUR DOM MON DOW CMD
```

[image]

Pratical examples:

- [Cron and Crontab usage and examples](http://www.pantz.org/software/cron/croninfo.html).
- [Cron Job Examples](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/).

Comment: Hi thanx for the confirmation. Is the syntax correct --sync I was not sure if it should be */5 * * * * --sync or just */5 * * * * sync

Comment: It should be `*/5 * * * * sync`